# Microsoft Graph and Partner Center in the same api gran

Tags: api, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I am looking to create a login that verifies a user account via the graph api and also verifies they are a microsoft partner via the partner api. I can easily get one grant or the other but can't seem to get both to work in one grant. I would rather not force the user to approve two different app approval boxes.

Is this possible:

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com/openid+profile+email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the limitations of azure ad, I don't believe you can request multiple scopes from different external resources like you're doing there. you will have to do two different requests. the token should stack with the resources, but you cannot call them both in one go. so no, that scope= you provided probably won't work or will only return the first scope.

Similar type question for reference.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1390